roots of non-linear factors of cyclotomic polynomial over finite field

I am confused about the roots in this example. The factors are cubic so there is no root of $\Phi_7(T)$ in $F_2$, and I wonder what the roots look like. I find the degree of the minimal polynomial is three so extension degree is also three, and the extension field is $F_8$, the roots above are all in $F_8$, right? But I also notice ($T^3+T+1$) must be an odd number,so the roots can not be divided by even number, What's wrong with my idea?

The roots of $\Phi_7$ are  all of the 7th roots of unity except 1. And the 7th roots of unity in $F_8$ are all the non-zero elements  of $F_8$ (because the multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic ---  in this case of order 7). So the roots of $\Phi_7$ in $F_8$ are all of the elements  of $F_8$ except 0 and 1.  And, as you said, "the roots can not be divided by an even number", simply because in a field of characteristic 2 like $F_8$, the only even "number" is 0.
